# Unable to delete file "ldlinux.sys" from a partition

Tags: ext4

I wanted to create live bootable USB of gparted via unetbootin. But by mistake I specified the device of USB as a partition of external HDD rather than the USB drive. I deleted all the files that unetbootin created in that HDD partition except one named "ldlinux.sys". I failed to do that via root user also. I'm unable to delete that file. You can please see the screen shot of the file in the HDD below.

[image: ldlinux.sys in external HDD]

Please see below for the message I'm getting while trying to delete the file via terminal.

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$ ll
total 92
drwxr-xr-x  12 ravi ravi  4096 Nov  6 11:04 ./
drwxr-x---+  5 root root  4096 Nov  8 09:28 ../
drwxrwxr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Jun 24 13:44 15GB_rsync/
drwxrwxr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Jun 24 15:13 3.5GB_rsync/
drwxrwxr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Jun 24 15:09 7.3GB_rsync/
drwx------   5 ravi ravi  4096 Nov  6 10:24 asus_21.06.2014/
drwxrwxr-x   4 ravi ravi  4096 Sep 24 09:18 asus_camera_27.09.14/
drwxrwxr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Oct  4 15:46 Dusherra_mau/
-r--r--r--   1 root root 32768 Nov  6 09:59 ldlinux.sys
drwx------   2 ravi ravi 16384 Apr 24  2014 lost+found/
drwx------   5 ravi ravi  4096 Jun 23 09:43 .Trash-1000/
drwxr-xr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Aug  3 12:31 ubuntu13.10_encripted_home_data/
drwxrwxr-x   3 ravi ravi  4096 Jun 24 15:15 ubuntu_home_rsync/

ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$ sudo rm ldlinux.sys
rm: cannot remove ‘ldlinux.sys’: Operation not permitted
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$
```

Then I noticed that the file isn't having executable permission. I felt that was the reason. So, to change the permissions of the file, I used chmod but it didn't happen & the error message was thrown as below.

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$ sudo chmod 777 ldlinux.sys
chmod: changing permissions of ‘ldlinux.sys’: Operation not permitted
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$ sudo chmod 555 ldlinux.sys
chmod: changing permissions of ‘ldlinux.sys’: Operation not permitted
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:/media/ravi/MyPassport Linux$ sudo chmod 666 ldlinux.sys
chmod: changing permissions of ‘ldlinux.sys’: Operation not permitted
```

Why it's happening so & how to delete the file?

Comment: please can you check whether other files are also had permission to remove file . did you mount filesystem in r/w mode? and which file system did you have in you external hardidisk

Comment: What does `lsattr ldlinux.sys` print?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could be that:

- The immutable flag is set. As PM 2Ring pointed out - you can use the `lsattr ldlinux.sys` command and look for the 'i' flag. If this is the case, a `chattr -i` should remove it.
- The filesystem is mounted read only (take at look at the output for the `mount` command)

Reference:

- [chattr wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr)

Comment: I will  try your way & update. It's not mounted read only as I mentioned in Q that  I was able to delete all other files except  this one.

Comment: Yes Criveti, great! Thank you. 'i' flag was set & I removed the way you told. Then I was able to delete the file.